# Delaying Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I delay JavaScript - I tried the following but it doesn't delay??:

```
setTimeout(document.getElementById("loading1").innerHTML="", 4000);
```

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("loading1").innerHTML="";}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function setHtml() {
  document.getElementById("loading1").innerHTML="";
}
setTimeout(setHtml, 4000);
```

Comment: Personally I would use an anonymous function. But for beginners this is clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: I agree. That was my reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

You would want to put your code inside of a function:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("loading1").innerHTML=""; }, 4000);
```