# How to delay code in javascript

Tags: javascript, render

```
  for(;i>=guessx;i--,z++)
 { (function(g,h){
    setTimeout(function(){cannon.style.left=g+ "px";},10*h);})(i,z);
 }

 missile.style.left=guessx + "px";
 missile.style.top=guessy + "px"; 
 alien.style.left=alienx + "px";
 alien.style.top=alieny + "px";
```

I am trying to develop a simple game. I want missile and alien position to be rendered only after
cannon position is updated. But here everything is updated simultaneously.

What can be done?

Comment: is the update a defined time interval or do you want to connect the render to just run when the other "says" its complete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delaying Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111311/delaying-javascript)