# How to add a delay in JQuery Code

Tags: jquery, delay

So the code below makes it so that an image fades in, how would I delay this by 7 seconds before the fade-in actually begins? Here's the code;

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".delayImg").each(function() {
    this.onload = function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 8000);
    };
    this.src = this.getAttribute("delayedSrc");
});
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Try searching first next time: http://api.jquery.com/?s=delay. The jQuery docs are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either jquery `delay()` or `setTimeout()`. Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaz2B/)** showing both.

As David Omid [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100919/746754), the javascript timeout is more flexible, because you can cancel it. `.delay()` method is used for delaying between queued jQuery effects.

HTML:

```
<img id="delayImg1" class="delayImg" src="imgSource">
<img id="delayImg2" class="delayImg" src="imgSource">
```

Javscript:

```
var m_delayTimer = null;
var m_delayTime = 5000;
function showImage()
{
    $("#delayImg2").animate({opacity: 1}, 2000)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delayImg1").each(function() {
        this.onload = function() {
           $(this).delay(m_delayTime).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        };        
    });
    m_delayTimer = window.setTimeout(showImage,m_delayTime);
});
```

CSS:

```
.delayImg
{
    opacity:0;        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [delay?](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delayImg").each(function() {
    this.onload = function() {
        $(this).delay(7000).animate({opacity: 1}, 8000);
    };
    this.src = this.getAttribute("delayedSrc");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 setTimeout(function() {
          // Do something after 7 seconds
    }, 7000);
```

The advantage of setTimeout is you can cancel the delay at any time by using the clearTimeout function like this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
              // Do something after 7 seconds
        }, 7000);
window.clearTimeout(timer); // Cancel the timer.
```

Comment: Where would I place this code? In which part of the jQuery? Thanks!:)

Answer (score -1):

something like this here. wrap around with the settimeout function that I think would acheive it.

[Delaying Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111311/delaying-javascript)